# How can I create a link to section initially hidden with slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several hidden divs and matching buttons to display them. 
When I click on a button the matching DIV is displaying. What I want to add is automatically scroll to the section displayed.

As the section is hidden, when I click the scroll is not complete (around 50px). If I click the button again the scroll becomes complete.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=image]').click(function() {
    var contentID = `#${this.id}Contenu`;
    var isContentVisible = $(contentID).is(':visible');
    if (!isContentVisible) {
      $('div[id$=Contenu]').hide();
      $(contentID).slideToggle(100);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.vignettesContenus {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00011f;
  display: none;
}

#contenus {
  background-color: #e8f1fa;
  color: black;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>


<div id="discovered">

  <div id="file" class="container">
    <a href="#edsContenu"> <input id="eds" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/eds.png" alt="EDS system" height="250px" width="250px" /></a>
  </div>


  <div id="file" class="container">
    <a href="#bridgeContenu"> <input id="bridge" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/pont.png" alt="pont photonique" height="250px" width="250px" /></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="edsContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

  <section id="content">

    <div id="text">

      <p>EDS©, pour Electrophotonic DataPhoton System » est un dispositif unique permettant d’acquérir, dans le spectre UV, les luminescences d’un corps soumis à son action. Ces luminescences sont caractéristiques de l’objet étudié. <br><br> Le schéma
        ci-dessous montre le processus de capture d'images utilisé par notre dispositif patenté EDS.</p>

      <img src="IMAGES/PNG/schema.png" width="500px" alt="laboratoire électrophotonique CORAMP">

      <p> L'objet à étudier est placé sur l'électrode.<br><br> Un champ électromagnétique distinctif et spécifique est généré, provoquant un effet de couronne. Celui- ci est enregistré par une caméra scientifique à très haute performance qui
        transmet à son tour l'image captée à un ordinateur pour analyse.<br><br> L'efficacité du dispositif et la qualité des résultats obtenus tiennent :
        <ul>
          <li>à la stabilité du générateur de champ EDS, générateur qui, par ailleurs, offre une définition informationnelle jamais obtenue jusqu'à présent ;</li>
          <li>aux propriétés de l'électrode spécialement fabriquée à cet effet ;</li>
          <li>aux outils de captation (optique : Fujinon High Resolution UV Lenses / caméra : scientific camera Hamamatsu) »</li>
        </ul>

      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>


<div id="bridgeContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

  <section id="content">

    <div id="text">

      <p>Les ponts photoniques constituent une découverte importante sur laquelle une communication a été présentée, en 2014, à l’occasion d’une rencontre internationale organisée par la Bioelectromagnetic Society en Afrique du Sud.<br><br> Des ponts
        photoniques peuvent apparaître ou non, dans le spectre UV, lorsque deux produits ou un système biologique et un produit sont placés à proximité l’un de l’autre sur une électrode spécifique appelée « support de conteneurs » et qu’un champ
        électromagnétique important est généré. </p>

      <br><br>

      <div id="imgPonts">
        <img src="IMAGES/JPG/doigt.jpg">
        <img src="IMAGES/JPG/support_conteneurs.jpg" title="Support">
        <img src="IMAGES/JPG/pont_photo_affinite.jpg" title="Pont d'affinité" alt="pont photonique affinité">
      </div>

      <br><br>

      <p>Ces ponts semblent indiquer une affinité entre les produits testés. En effet, dans le cas contraire, on n’observe aucun échange photonique, voire à l’inverse une barrière telle que la montre l’image ci-dessous.</p>

      <div id="imgPonts"> <img src="IMAGES/JPG/pont_photon_repulsion.jpg" title="Pont répulsion" alt="pont photonique répulsion"></div>

      <br>

      <p>Ce phénomène singulier est régulièrement utilisé expérimentalement dans différents domaines de recherche (agro-alimentaire, alicaments, principes actifs, eaux...). Il est possible d’en mesurer les valeurs et ainsi de classifier le degré
        d’affinité en fonction des différents produits évalués.</p>

    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `slideToggle() !== scrollTo()`. You need to scroll the window to the elements position. `slideToggle()` simply toggles a slide animation. You can think of a toggle as 'expanding' or 'collapsing' in place.

jQuery def:

> Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

The reason it goes directly to the element the next time you click on it, is because your logic is malformed:

```
if(!isContentVisible){ 
  $('div[id$=Contenu]').hide();
```

You hide all the divs with an id like that *only* if it's not hidden. So it's not working properly, it just appears to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=image]').click(function() {
    $('div[id$=Contenu]').hide();
    var contentID = `#${this.id}Contenu`;
    var isContentVisible = $(contentID).is(':visible');
    if (!isContentVisible) {
      $(contentID).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.vignettesContenus {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00011f;
  display: none;
}

#contenus {
  background-color: #e8f1fa;
  color: black;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>


<div id="discovered">

  <div id="file" class="container">
    <a href="#edsContenu"> <input id="eds" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/eds.png" alt="EDS system" height="250px" width="250px" /></a>
  </div>


  <div id="file" class="container">
    <a href="#bridgeContenu"> <input id="bridge" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/pont.png" alt="pont photonique" height="250px" width="250px" /></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="edsContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

  <section id="content">

    <div id="text">

      <p>EDS©, pour Electrophotonic DataPhoton System » est un dispositif unique permettant d’acquérir, dans le spectre UV, les luminescences d’un corps soumis à son action. Ces luminescences sont caractéristiques de l’objet étudié. <br><br> Le schéma
        ci-dessous montre le processus de capture d'images utilisé par notre dispositif patenté EDS.</p>

      <img src="IMAGES/PNG/schema.png" width="500px" alt="laboratoire électrophotonique CORAMP">

      <p> L'objet à étudier est placé sur l'électrode.<br><br> Un champ électromagnétique distinctif et spécifique est généré, provoquant un effet de couronne. Celui- ci est enregistré par une caméra scientifique à très haute performance qui
        transmet à son tour l'image captée à un ordinateur pour analyse.<br><br> L'efficacité du dispositif et la qualité des résultats obtenus tiennent :
        <ul>
          <li>à la stabilité du générateur de champ EDS, générateur qui, par ailleurs, offre une définition informationnelle jamais obtenue jusqu'à présent ;</li>
          <li>aux propriétés de l'électrode spécialement fabriquée à cet effet ;</li>
          <li>aux outils de captation (optique : Fujinon High Resolution UV Lenses / caméra : scientific camera Hamamatsu) »</li>
        </ul>

      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>


<div id="bridgeContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

  <section id="content">

    <div id="text">

      <p>Les ponts photoniques constituent une découverte importante sur laquelle une communication a été présentée, en 2014, à l’occasion d’une rencontre internationale organisée par la Bioelectromagnetic Society en Afrique du Sud.<br><br> Des ponts
        photoniques peuvent apparaître ou non, dans le spectre UV, lorsque deux produits ou un système biologique et un produit sont placés à proximité l’un de l’autre sur une électrode spécifique appelée « support de conteneurs » et qu’un champ
        électromagnétique important est généré. </p>

      <br><br>

      <div id="imgPonts">
        <img src="IMAGES/JPG/doigt.jpg">
        <img src="IMAGES/JPG/support_conteneurs.jpg" title="Support">
        <img src="IMAGES/JPG/pont_photo_affinite.jpg" title="Pont d'affinité" alt="pont photonique affinité">
      </div>

      <br><br>

      <p>Ces ponts semblent indiquer une affinité entre les produits testés. En effet, dans le cas contraire, on n’observe aucun échange photonique, voire à l’inverse une barrière telle que la montre l’image ci-dessous.</p>

      <div id="imgPonts"> <img src="IMAGES/JPG/pont_photon_repulsion.jpg" title="Pont répulsion" alt="pont photonique répulsion"></div>

      <br>

      <p>Ce phénomène singulier est régulièrement utilisé expérimentalement dans différents domaines de recherche (agro-alimentaire, alicaments, principes actifs, eaux...). Il est possible d’en mesurer les valeurs et ainsi de classifier le degré
        d’affinité en fonction des différents produits évalués.</p>

    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: actually I want animate it with slow motion. When I change the slideToggle duration to 0 it works perfectly like your code. But when it's slideToggle(500) it doesn't work. How can I animate it properly?